# How do I get the Assembly version from my sln into a continuous integration labeller?

Tags: assemblies, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I want to obtain the assembly version from my solution and apply that to a cc.net label.  I think I'm doing it backwards since all the info out there have the CI server set the version.  But I'm not sure how to integrate different release versions and the development branch into CI.  Every time we release we up the revision number.  Would/should I add a new project in cc.net for every branch?  Is there a way to automatically get the latest branch?  Sorry for so many different questions in one...question.  I'm new to this CI stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this all much easier if you switch to [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).  I've wrestled with so many nant scripts/cruisecontrol config files in the past I'm almost blind from angle brackets.

I cried like the accountant who was shown the first spreadsheet program when I started messing with TeamCity.  It will make your life 1000% easier.

Comment: Well Team City isn't free, and that's a big issue with the company.  Hudson looked cool.

Comment: The professional edition *is* free. That's 20 users and 20 projects. If you want more, even then the enterprise edition is only about the same cost as a single msdn license for a year.  If you're new to CI I would still strongly recommend TeamCity.

Comment: You can also run multiple instances of the free professional edition, so if you can segregate your projects/users sensibly you need never hit the 20/20 limit.

Answer (score 2):

FinalBuilder and the AssemblyInfo Updater

[Update : Cool, can't add hyperlinks. Put FinalBuilder and 3xw en dotcom in the end in front of the following url:)
/Products/FinalBuilder/FeatureMatrix/FeaturesCompilerActions/tabid/98/Default.aspx

1. Use "PropertySet Define" based on .NET Assembly Numbers
2. Use "PropertySet Load"
3. Use "PropertySet Incremement"
4. Use "AssemblyInfo Updater" to save it again

And you're done. :)